# Prining the Grid View values

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Using VS2005

I am using GridView in my web page, i want to print the gridview values....

How to write a code for the printing the grid view values.....

I want to print the full contents of the gridview by pressing the button.

Can any one provide a code.

Comment: can you plz provide more information about printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is good resources on google, follow the link :[print gridview](http://www.google.com/search?q=print+gridview&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)